# Screen capture video in iOS programmatically

Tags: objective-c, xcode, screen-capture, avassetwriter

I'm trying to create a UIView that allows a user to tap a button in i and record the screen (not make a video from the camera), then save it to the document folder.  I've seen a couple of SO articles here that talk about AVAssetWriter and make references to this link: http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/673 , but that link appears to be dead.

But no one has actually shown a solution or provided any examples on how to accomplish.  Anyone have any ideas or can point me in the right direction? This should be simpler than it is.

Thanks,
Doug

Comment: Although I have not fully found a solution, I did found a GREAT reference with sourcecode here: http://www.slideshare.net/invalidname/advanced-media-manipulation-with-av-foundation   and the sourcecode example: http://www.subfurther.com/blog/category/avfoundation/  in the file: ATMScreenRecorderTest.zip

Comment: Any Solution on screen video recording along with user Audio?

Comment: @Doug, did you manage to get an answer for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link is not dead.

http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/673

If you check the comments, there is also some code that will mix audio & video and save it as a quicktime movie.

If you still can't access the link, there is a guy selling the same code on binpress:

http://www.binpress.com/app/ios-screen-capture-view/1038

Comment: Well it's dead again. This is why link-only answers are bad.

Comment: @OrangeDog - the link is working fine for me! That page contains a LOT of code and some explanations - too much for a StackOverflow answer. I could copy the code into GitHub or a Gist but then it would still be a 'link-only' answer.

Comment: Hi @noodl_es since this is a dated answer would this still be the best way record video of a UIView (not full screen)? Thanks for your time! Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34956713/simplified-screen-capture-record-video-of-only-what-appears-within-the-layers-o

Answer (score 3):

Another useful project for this is RecordMyScreen, found here:
https://github.com/coolstar/RecordMyScreen

Comment: Yeah, I've been following that project for awhile and that team did a FANTASTIC job of building it and working thru the issues.

Comment: @Doug and Tim do you guys know if this project can record video?

Comment: Hi Tim since this is a dated answer is this still the best way to do screen capture? Specifically, we need to capture the contents from a UIView, not the whole screen. Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34956713/simplified-screen-capture-record-video-of-only-what-appears-within-the-layers-o. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Crashalot I'm not sure about for just one view, but now plugging your device in to your Mac with its Lightning / USB cable, opening Quicktime, and choosing a screen recording, and then recording video that way, is the easiest way to record your screen.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach it is using a feedback library such as BlitFeedback, which includes effortless screen video-capturing.

Comment: Hey tony, can blitFeeback, record a screen programmatically in an app? Thanks for the post