# Screen Recording using AvCaptureSession

Tags: iphone, ios, video, screenshot, avcapturesession

In my application I want to record view with Still Images. 
Is there any way to take screenshot of view using AvCaptureSession?
What I will do is ,will capture images of view and after that will use all images to make video of that view.
I have refer this link also 
https://github.com/immortalLion/iPhoneScreenRecord/tree/master/ScreenCaptureViewTest.
I know we can capture screenshot using IOSurface but I don't want to capture whole screen instead I want to capture view only.
I'd like to set Framerate & with Rendering Good Scale
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should Check this answer [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334977/screen-capture-video-in-ios-programmatically) Hope this will help you.
http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/673

Answer (score 0):

This will capture the view as image and you can specify the frame of the view.

```
- (UIImage *)captureView:(UIView *)view {
        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenRect.size);

        CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        [[UIColor blackColor] set];
        CGContextFillRect(ctx, screenRect);

        [view.layer renderInContext:ctx];

        UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return newImage;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I want to capture view with running video.