# Rendering a UIView in which something gets animated and export a video from it

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

How can I record a video for a certain period of time from a UIView just like we are recording a portion of the phone's screen?

Comment: Just video, like a screen capture, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Screen capture video in iOS programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334977/screen-capture-video-in-ios-programmatically)

Comment: In fact it is the same question and ironically I didn't find the link you suggested when i searched, thank you, but! the solution which has been provided in here is much better than those in that link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### use [Glimpse](https://github.com/wess/Glimpse)

Glimpse allows you to create videos from UIViews. More documentation is here, but basically it records animations and actions as they happen by taking screen shots of a UIView in a series and then creating a quicktime video and saving it to your app’s document folder.

Here is a sample usage:

```
#import <Glimpse/Glimpse.h>

@implementation myViewController
- (void)viewDidAppear
{
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];

        // Create a new Glimpse object.
        Glimpse *glimpse = [[Glimpse alloc] init];

        // Start recording and tell Glimpse what to do when you are finished
        [glimpse startRecordingView:self.view onCompletion:^(NSURL *fileOuputURL) {
            NSLog(@"DONE WITH OUTPUT: %@", fileOuputURL.absoluteString);
        }];

        // Create a subview for this example
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(self.view.bounds, 40.0f 40.0f)];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        view.alpha = 0.0f;

        [self.view addSubview:view];

        // We are going to record the view fading in.
        [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^{
            view.alpha = 1.0f;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            // Since our animation is complete, lets tell Glimpse to stop recording.
            [glimpse stop];
        }];
 }
@end
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, do you think i can attach an audio file to the exported video? How can i achieve that?

Comment: is it compatible with iOS 11?

Comment: @clause, cant see why not.

Comment: Does that cause audio to be lost?

Comment: not working, Don't waster your time on above library

Comment: Sorry, this totally works. If not @mehul, perhaps you should elaborate?